# screens and navigation architecture - multiple types of user - react native

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I have 3 types of users (admin, dealer, user). Each one has either a different content through the pages or many extra pages, and those pages have not to be accessed by another type of user through URLs or something like that.
I've many questions here:

1. Regarding navigation architecture, should I have two different navigation structures like :
   **dashboardDrawerNavigator, HomeDrawerNavigator, dashboardTab,...**
   or just one navigation structure and the screens would be sorted into groups like  `user ? group 1:dealer group 2 ...` and that would
   be applied to all navigators (tab, stack, drawer)
2. According to different content on the page
   **For example** I have profile screen with (preview, update, create ) modes for the three user types with a bit different and  different APIs
   The best practice is either to use a separate screens in different folder structures (each user owns its screens even if they're the same content), or conditional render?
3. For these (preview, update, create) is it best practice to separate the preview into another screen ???
   because I did it before with React on the same page and it was too ugly due to the large content